# Django : class based view with multiple permissions

Tags: python, django, class, permissions, django-class-based-views

I am trying to create a class based view with different permissions per function. I have already created my permissions in a file that I import :

**utils.py**

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class IsOwner(BasePermission):
    """
    Check if the user who made the request is owner.
    Use like that : permission_classes = [IsOwner]
    """
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        #     return True
        return obj.user == request.user

class IsAdmin(BasePermission):
    """
    Check if the user who made the request is admin.
    Use like that : permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_admin

class BaseView(APIView):
    """
    Check if a user is authenticated
    """
    authentication_classes = [
        TokenAuthentication,
    ]

class AdminOrOwnerView(APIView):
    """
    Check if a user is admin or owner
    """
    authentication_classes = ( IsOwner | IsAdmin,)
```

I want to create a class with different method. The GET method would allow admins to have a view of all users. The POST method would allow any user to connect.

I have already created the serializer for each of these methods but I cannot assign different permissions per method.

This is my class :

```
class Users(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        """Only for admin"""
        try:
            user = Users.objects.all()
        except User.DoesNotExist():
            return HttpResponse(status=404)
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        """For everyone"""
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.error)
```

How I can apply my permissions on each of the methods separately ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to create a permission class like this:

```
class CustomPermissionClass(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            # logic for GET method
        elif request.method == 'POST'
            # logic for POST metod
        # default logic
```

And add it to your view:

```
class Users(APIView):
    permission_classes = [CustomPermissionClass]
```

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought of this solution